# Getting Pagecontent in HMENU

Tags: typo3, typoscript

i'm creating a menu with HMENU in Typoscript. Now my question: is there a possibility to check if the linked paged as any content. if it has none how can i disable the link?

i'm generate the menu with the following code

```
  NAV = HMENU
  NAV{
  entryLevel = 0
  wrap = <ul class="nav">|</ul>
  1 = TMENU
  1.NO {
    allWrap = <li class="nav-button"><p class="title">|</p></li>
  }
  1.ACT = 1
  1.ACT {
    allWrap = <li class="nav-button selected"><p class="title">|</p></li>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested!

You can check with [numRows](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Numrows/Index.html) if there is any tt_content record on that page (you can use [WHERE](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Select/Index.html) if you want to check only specific records). With [required](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html) you define, that this menu item will only be rendered if numRows is greater then 1.

```
NAV.1.NO.allStdWrap.required.numRows {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    # uid of this page, is the pid of the records to look for
    pidInList.field = uid
  }
}
NAV.1.ACT.allStdWrap < NAV.1.NO.allStdWrap
```